# How is this trival?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I was reading [an article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05984.pdf) today and on section 2 it is indicated that if we are given a Radon Measure $\mu$, and a real $p$ then fast convergence entails trivially almost sure convergence, where fast convergence of a sequence $g_n$ toward $g$ is defined by :

$$\sum ||g_n-g||_{L^p(\mu)}<\infty$$

I must be lacking mathematical culture in integration theory but I don't see how is this trivial or even true.

Does anyone has a clue about how to show this claim ?

Best regards

Comment: The proof of the Riesz-Fischer theorem (i.e. the statement "$L^p$ is complete") given in Royden and Fitzpatrick uses this fact. In the fourth edition, the Lebesgue measure case is on pages 146 and 147, and does not require any techniques specific to the real line. The central technique for getting the a.e. convergence is the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: @ Ian : Thank you I'll check for the reference. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p=\infty$ this is clear; fast convergence implies essentially uniform convergence. Suppose $p<\infty$.

Fast convergence is much more than you need here. All you need is the weaker condition $$\sum||g_n-g||_p^p<\infty.$$That says $$\int\sum|g_n-g|^p<\infty.$$Hence the integrand is finite almost everywhere, which says (much more than) $g_n\to g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @ David : Thank's a lot this is convincing for a positive or probability measure $\mu$ but I 'm not totally sure if this is enough for Radon Measures (as I am not very acquainted to those) specifically two points still remain unclear to me, the "legality" of the intervertion of sum integral and the finitness argument.  Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge This interchange can be done with just monotone convergence.

Comment: @TheBridge It's just monotone convergence. When you said "Radon measure" I assumed you meant a positive measure. Doesn't matter - if $\mu$ is a complex measure then by definition $||f||_p^p=\int|f|^p\,d|\mu|$, and $|\mu|$ is a positive measure.